# How to retrieve a secret token from a redirect url during an OAuth flow in python?

Tags: oauth-2.0, python-requests

**Context**
I am using an API to retrieve data. This API requires credentials that can be passed through browser authentication/authorisation.

Using one of the endpoints I can generate a link to the authorization server. I then pass this link to the user (a client) who logs in and then a secret identifier is passed in the redirect URL. I can chose the redirect URL when creating the OAuth link.

When I do this process myself, I can take the secret_id manually from the redirect_URL and then use it to send a request to the API.

**Ask**
How can I reproduce the above manual step of retrieving the secret id from the redirect URL in a programmatic way when done by a different user than me?

The redirect URL including the secret_id looks like this: https://www.example.com/?<secret_id>=

For now, I don't expect to include this flow in a website. I just would like to know whether it's possible to retrieve the value of the secret_id from the redirect URL.

I am using Python with the requests package in a jupyter notebook.

Thanks!